# Restoring a variable after jupyter notebook crashed

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, crash, ram, restore

In main function I was appending data to a list. For hours
Then my notebook crashed
Now I can't even save my .ipynb ("Unexpected error while saving file: Population must be a sequence. For dicts or sets, use sorted(d)")
And now my .ipynb file is as big as 113 000 KB.

Can I somehow restore this variable / data?

I tried to use %whos but there's nothing like my variable
Also there's %store but it should have supposedly been used in advance

Comment: If you didn't store variables by using a command such as the ```%store```, it's gone.